# Unable to get a setting from settings file in django

Tags: python, django, settings

I've a setting say `gi` in `settings.py` file. I've created a separate python file (i.e. I'm not using it in views) and used import statement as:

```
from django.conf import settings
```

but when I try to access `settings.gi`, it says that `'Settings' object has no attribute 'gi'`. What's missing? :s

Comment: I don't know if this is important, but the error says **S**ettings, while you are trying to access **s**ettings. Could it be that you accidently used a capital s?

Comment: @BrtH No, you can look into the source code of django.conf, you would see the `settings` is an wrapper around the project `settings` module.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From the Django docs on [creating your own settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#creating-your-own-settings) states:

> Setting names are in all uppercase.

Try renaming the setting to `GI`.

Comment: But that's just a convention? I'm using some existing code so I won't rename the setting as it will also be used in other apps

Comment: I used this code to view settings `for property, value in vars(theObject).iteritems():
    print property, ": ", value` it just shows one property that is _wrapped

Comment: If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4/django/conf/__init__.py#L82) for the settings object, you can see that variables that are not upper case will be ignored. Maybe the word 'convention' in the docs isn't strong enough. If you don't want to rename the variable, then that's up to you, but Django won't treat it as a 'setting', and you'll need to find a different way to import it.

Comment: I've submitted a pull request to make the documentation clearer: https://github.com/django/django/pull/6546/files

Answer (score 0):

The project must be added on the PYTHONPATH and the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE has to be defined.
Please refer to the commands mentioned below.

```
export PYTHONPATH=PATH_OF_PROJECT
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings
```

Comment: All my other settings are working properly. For example database connectivity is working and syncdb works. The only problem is with one file which uses settings from settings file.

Comment: Could you post the rest of the import statements of the file from which you are unable access the project's setting file. May be their is a collision in import or module name? Try in caps as mentioned by Alasdir.