# function in django settings?

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I would like to add a function to my django settings.py (returning an incremented url).

However, my attempt to add this function is not working...

```
'Settings' object has no attribute 'nextCdnUrl'
```

Here is the relevant bits of the settings.py file:

```
CDN_MIN_I = 1
CDN_MAX_I = 6
CDN_I = CDN_MIN_I

def nextCdnUrl( ):
    CDN_I += 1
    if CDN_I > CDN_MAX_I:
        CDN_I = CDN_MIN_I

    return CDN_BASE_URL.replace( "_i", str(CDN_I) )
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Settings must be all caps, in this case `NEXTCDNURL`.

However, it looks like you are trying to alter `CDN_I` in your function. It's not a good idea to [alter settings at runtime](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#altering-settings-at-runtime).

Comment: No, it mustn't be in all caps.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631194/unable-to-get-a-setting-from-settings-file-in-django

Comment: You can have any name for a settings variable/function. Try adding this to your settings file and `def meow(i):
    return "meow"` and see it print when you do `settingsfile.meow(1)`

Comment: The down votes are too hasty. Read the question I linked to above, click through to the source code I linked to, and try importing settings the recommended way: `from django.conf import settings`

Comment: No, the question is how do I add a function to my settings file. Not how do I manage to do a proper setting.

Comment: Sigh. The question has a traceback, I've explained the reason for the traceback, and have been down voted for it, which is frustrating. My attempts to convince you have failed, so I give up.

Comment: You are indeed correct, I stand corrected and apologize. I looked at it from the wrong angle. Sorry!

Comment: No worries, I was the one at fault here! Have a great christmas, mate! )

Comment: Merry Christmas to you too :)